# Stack and Heap Viewer

Tags: .net, clr, heap-memory, stack-memory

Is there a free Stack and Heap viewer for .NET which shows what types are allocated on the stack and the heap. I need this for a training I will be conducting.

Comment: Check [SOS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2007/11/15/sos-your-visual-studio.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [WinDbg with SOS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windbg/info) for that. Attach to the process and use the following commands:

`!dumpheap -stat` will list all objects on the managed heap.

`!clrstack -a` will list the managed call stack including parameters and locals for the current thread. Keep in mind that release builds may limit the number of available locals.

`~Xs` switch to thread X.

SOS has loads of other useful commands to inspect managed applications.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout CLR profiler

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/12/17/clr-profiler-2-0-available.aspx

And another article that could help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309515.aspx